# ehcache 2.5.0 disk storage

Tags: ehcache, ehcache-bigmemory

BAckground:  I'm using ehcache as a cache implementation in a Spring 3.1 application.
I'm storing large items (files of 100 MB for example) ... I activated the Disk Storage option (overflowToDisk = true ) in ehcache.xml.

My question is  : does ehcache load the whole object (large object in my case) in memory or does it stream it from the disk ?

Version of ehcache is 2.5.0

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it loads the whole object though we have talked about providing a streaming interface for both entering and retrieving values. Is this something that would interest you?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what we had in mind. Is this feature scheduled for the next release?

Comment: We are looking at it. Ping me at my  terracotta e-mail address which is just my first name. I'm collecting use cases and people to test with on this sort of thing.

Comment: Please keep this question up-to-date as this is a feature that might intest others too. I am running into the same issue here.